# Updating UILabel from another ViewController

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

new to Xamarin and iOS so this may be a silly question:

Basically, I have a UITabBarController, NewGameScreen.cs (with NewGameScreen.designer.cs and NewGameScreen.xib) and as one of the tabs, I have StatsScreen.cs (with StatsScreen.designer.cs and StatsScreen.xib). StatsScreen has some labels that I want to modify from NewGameScreen, so I created a new StatsScreen object:

```
StatsScreen stats = new StatsScreen ();
```

Then I call a method as such:

```
stats.setStats (day, debt, money, bank, health, location); // All of the parameters here are local variables
```

The method looks like this:

```
public void setStats (int day, long debt, long money, long bank, int health, string location)
{
    LabelDay.Text = day.ToString ();
    LabelDebt.Text = debt.ToString ();
    LabelMoney.Text = money.ToString ();
    LabelBank.Text = bank.ToString ();
    LabelHealth.Text = health.ToString ();
    LabelLocation.Text = location;
}
```

When I run and click, I get:

**A System.NullReferenceException was thrown. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I have tried changing things around, calling different sequences of methods, but I seem to only be able to call setStats from within the class that it resides, StatsScreen.

I must be making a fatal error, it shouldn't be difficult to update a UILabel like this.

Essentially, I have a Tab Controller (NewGameScreen) with 3 tabs in. I want the Tab Controller to manage the 3 subviews (tabs) as I need to share data between the 3 screens and thought that having an overseeing class would be beneficial such that if I set some variables in NewGameScreen, I can update each of the 3 subviews (one of them being StatsScreen).

How would you recommend that I go about this, I feel that I am misunderstanding the ViewController system.

Kind regards. [Link to full project code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26406416/DealerGame.zip/)

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: First, you are trying to update a new instance of a View, not the instance that (presumably) already exists.  You need to get a reference to the view that already exists and expose a property or method that will allow you to access it's controls.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip, I will try and correct this. Appreciate it.

Comment: If I understand your example correctly, StatsScreen inherits from UIViewController, correct? If so, you would instantiate this and add to the UITabBarController parent instance; internally, the framework instantiates the underlying view based on the default code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Object not set" could be due to a lot of things.    I would highly recommend figuring out where in the code does it throw the exception?  Do you make it to the setStats method, and it errors in there?  Possible errors are:

- One of the label's is not mapped properly to an outlet, and that is throwing an error.  To figure out, put a debugger breakpoint in the method, and mouse over all of the label properties, make sure they are not null.  This has got me a couple of times.
- The variable passed in is null, and calling `ToString()` throws an exception (not likely though since you have all value types)
- Some unrelated error is being thrown from somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode to design the interface, and those elements are outlets connected to the UI?

Then the problem is simple: those elements will be null from the creation of the object until the ViewDidLoad method is called.   Which is when the values will be set.